# Communication between 2 LocalScripts

Tags: lua, roblox

I have no idea how to establish connection between two LocalScripts in my game. I have a LocalScript for a fireball mechanic in the StarterCharacterScripts folder and a Sprint script in the StarerGUI folder.

Basically, I want to decrease the player's stamina from the Sprint LocalScript whenever the player launches a fireball.

I already tried searching for solutions on youtube.

Fireball LocalScript in StarterCharacterScripts:

```
local fireballModel = game.ReplicatedStorage.Fireball
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local canFire = true
local maxCharges = 3
local currentCharges = maxCharges
local rechargeTime = 2
local fireballSpeed = 12
local fireballDistance = 20
local FIREBALL_STAMINA_DECREASE = 15

local rightPunchAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
rightPunchAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13525189932"

local leftPunchAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
leftPunchAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://13525204331"

local currentHand = "Right"
local punchAnimationPlaying = false

game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        print("Fireball")

        if canFire and currentCharges > 0 and not punchAnimationPlaying then
            canFire = false
            currentCharges -= 1
            
            
            local character = player.Character
            local humanoid = character and character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
            if humanoid then
                punchAnimationPlaying = true
                local punchAnimation
                local handPart
                if currentHand == "Right" then
                    punchAnimation = humanoid:LoadAnimation(rightPunchAnimation)
                    handPart = character:WaitForChild("RightHand")
                    currentHand = "Left"
                else
                    punchAnimation = humanoid:LoadAnimation(leftPunchAnimation)
                    handPart = character:WaitForChild("LeftHand")
                    currentHand = "Right"
                end
                punchAnimation:Play()

                punchAnimation.Stopped:Wait()
                punchAnimationPlaying = false
                canFire = true

                local fireball = fireballModel:Clone()
                fireball.Parent = workspace

                local directionUnitVector = (mouse.Hit.p - handPart.Position).Unit

                fireball.CFrame = CFrame.new(handPart.Position, handPart.Position + directionUnitVector * fireballDistance)
                
                
                
                -----damage---------------------------
                local damageAmount = 25
                local hasHit = false

                fireball.Touched:Connect(function(part)
                    if not hasHit then
                    local humanoid = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                    if humanoid then
                        if humanoid.Parent.Name ~= player.Name then
                            print("target hit")
                                humanoid:TakeDamage(damageAmount)
                                hasHit=true
                            fireball:Destroy()
                            end
                            end
                    end
                end)
                ---------------------------------------
                
                spawn(function()
                    local startTime = tick()
                    while tick() - startTime < fireballDistance / fireballSpeed do
                        fireball.Position += directionUnitVector * fireballSpeed * (tick() - startTime)
                        wait()
                    end
                    fireball:Destroy()
                end)
            end
        end
    end
end)

spawn(function()
    while true do
        wait(rechargeTime)
        if currentCharges < maxCharges then
            currentCharges += 1
        end
    end
end)
```

Sprint LocalScript (handles stamina) in StarterGUI:

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local SPRINT_SPEED = 25
local DEFAULT_SPEED = 10
local MAXIMUM_STAMINA = 200
local Crouch_Speed = 4
local exhausted_speed = 4

local STAMINA_DECREASE = 0.25
local SPRINT_KEY = Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift
local StaminaAmount = MAXIMUM_STAMINA
local crouching = false
local sprinting = false
local exhausted = true
local FIREBALL_STAMINA_DECREASE = 15

local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:wait()
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera

local Exterior = script.Parent.Exterior
local Bar = Exterior.Bar

Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart").CanCollide = false

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input)
        if Input.KeyCode == SPRINT_KEY and crouching == false then 
        sprinting = true
        game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(cam, TweenInfo.new(0.2, Enum.EasingStyle.Cubic, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {FieldOfView = cam.FieldOfView*1.125}):Play()
    end
        end)
game["Run Service"].RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if StaminaAmount > 0 and not exhausted then
        if sprinting and Humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 and Humanoid.WalkSpeed == SPRINT_SPEED then 
                StaminaAmount -= STAMINA_DECREASE
        end
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount == 0  then
        sprinting = false
        exhausted = true
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = exhausted_speed
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount <50 and exhausted==false and sprinting==true    then
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 50
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = SPRINT_SPEED
    elseif StaminaAmount <50 and exhausted==true then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = exhausted_speed
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 20
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount > 50 and exhausted==true then
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 50
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = DEFAULT_SPEED
        exhausted = false
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount > 50 and Humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude > 0 and sprinting==true then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = SPRINT_SPEED
        exhausted = false
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount > 0 and Humanoid.MoveDirection.Magnitude == 0 and sprinting==true then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed= DEFAULT_SPEED
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount < 50 then
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 20
else
        Humanoid.JumpPower = 50
    end
    
    if StaminaAmount < MAXIMUM_STAMINA then 
        Exterior.Visible = true

        local Formula = (StaminaAmount/MAXIMUM_STAMINA)
        Bar:TweenSizeAndPosition(UDim2.new(1, 0, Formula, 0), UDim2.new(0, 0, 1-Formula, 0), Enum.EasingDirection.Out, Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, 0.1, true)

                if  Humanoid.WalkSpeed ~= SPRINT_SPEED then
                    StaminaAmount += STAMINA_DECREASE
                    end
    else
        Exterior.Visible = false
    end
end)

UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(Input)
    if Input.KeyCode == SPRINT_KEY then
        sprinting = false
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = DEFAULT_SPEED
        game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(cam, TweenInfo.new(0.2, Enum.EasingStyle.Cubic, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {FieldOfView = cam.FieldOfView/1.125}):Play()
    end
    
    if Input.KeyCode == SPRINT_KEY and crouching == true then
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Crouch_Speed
        game:GetService("TweenService"):Create(cam, TweenInfo.new(0.2, Enum.EasingStyle.Cubic, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {FieldOfView = cam.FieldOfView}):Play()
    end
    end)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to communicate between Scripts and LocalScripts is to use a [BindableEvent](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BindableEvent) or [BindableFunction](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BindableFunction). You essentially create a BindableEvent instance in a known location, and then both scripts use it to communicate.

So try this :

1. Create a BindableEvent in ReplicatedStorage
2. Name it something like **UseStamina**
3. In your Fireball LocalScript, find the BindableEvent and fire it whenever you use the spell.

```lua
local FIREBALL_STAMINA_DECREASE = 15

-- find the BindableEvent
local UseStamina = game.ReplicatedStorage.UseStamina

-- when the player fires the fireball, decrease the stamina
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        print("Fireball")

        if canFire and currentCharges > 0 and not punchAnimationPlaying then
            canFire = false
            currentCharges -= 1

            -- tell the stamina script to decrease the stamina
            UseStamina:Fire(FIREBALL_STAMINA_DECREASE)
```

4. In your Sprinting LocalScript, find the BindableEvent and listen for when something fires it, and decrease the stamina accordingly.

```lua
-- find the BindableEvent
local UseStamina = game.ReplicatedStorage.UseStamina

-- listen for when any script says to use up some stamina
UseStamina.Event:Connect(function(amountToUse)
    -- prevent StaminaAmount from ever going negative
    StaminaAmount -= math.min(StaminaAmount, amountToUse)
end)
```

Comment: You can also use a BindableFunction instead to ask, "Do I have enough stamina?", and the function can return true of false.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would make a `BoolValue` parented to the Sprint local script, the fireball will be able to access it and change it so that the sprint script can monitor it and make changes inside the script based on the current state of that value.

There's probably a lot of ways to communicate between local scripts, I'm not sure whether the one I suggested is the best or not however its always worked for me to do things like that.